# Address binding issue

Tags: java, gradle, jetty

I am trying to run a web application (which is a servlet + gradle project). I am using Jetty to run the application. When I run the application , I am getting the error:

Address already in use
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip'.

When, I enter  localhost:8080  , I used to get jenkins default page, So I uninstalled jenkins and tried again, but getting the same error.

Please help in resolving this issue, also how do we get to know which application is running on corresponding port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command "netstat". Look for the line in which the column "remote address" ends with ":8080".

Depending on the OS you're running:

Windows:

```
netstat -b -n -a -p TCP
```

The process is printed above the line.

Linux:

```
 netstat -a -n -p | grep 8080
```

The process is printed as the last column of the line.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Found one more useful cmd 
lsof -i :8080